# Add some text to an existing variable in JS

Tags: javascript

Why this code do not work ?

```
var text = '';
var text += 'How ';
var text += 'are ';
var text += 'you ';
var text += 'today ?';

alert(text);
```

I'm trying to `alert()` : How are you today ?

This is a voluntary basic code.

Thanks.

Comment: take var out after the first one =]

Comment: you only need to define `text` once, kill the `var` in front of text after the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redeclaring the variable on each line.

You should use `var` to declare the variable first.

After, you could add some other text by using the `+=` symbol.

```
var text = '';
text += 'How ';
text += 'are ';
text += 'you ';
text += 'today ?';
alert(text);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are re-declaring `text` variable each time instead of just updating its value. You should do:

```
var text = '';
text += 'How ';
text += 'are ';
text += 'you ';
text += 'today ?';

alert(text);
```

Comment: comprehensively explained

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring the variable each time. Drop the extra `var`s, you only need the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `var` when you append new value.

```
var text = '';
text += 'How ';
text += 'are ';
text += 'you ';
text += 'today ?';

alert(text);
```

You just use `var` when you want to declare a **JavaScript variable**

Answer (score 1):

Each time you use `var text`, you are re-declaring the variable.

```js
var text = '';
text += 'How ';
text += 'are ';
text += 'you ';
text += 'today ?';

alert(text);
```

Here's a different approach, using an array:

```js
var text = [];

text.push('How');
text.push('are');
text.push('you');
text.push('today');

alert( text.join(' ') );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer in a bit more depth.

---

The `var` keyword could be considered a constructor. What a constructor does is creates something, of a class, with all default values. By default, values constructed with the `var` keyword are `null`.

With that in mind, what you are doing in reality is redeclaring the `text` variable as `null`, and then assigning it your next value, but you are doing this each time you want to add something, therefore appending your new value onto nothing, meaning it is assigned to that value, and that value alone.

This is your solution: (don't redeclare)

```
var text = "Hello",
    name = "Josh";

text += " World";
text += ", My name is ";
text += name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use += while declaring a variable in JavaScript.

Also, you are making multiple declarations of the same variable.

Try this instead -

https://jsfiddle.net/abto5aLj/

```
var text = '';
text += 'How ';
text += 'are ';
text += 'you ';
text += 'today ?';
alert(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are redefining the variable `text` every time our are trying to add a new piece of string.

You have to use the [variable statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) `var` only the first time you are defining a new variable (`text` in your case).

Here the complete example with the correction:

```js
var text = '';
text += 'How ';
text += 'are ';
text += 'you ';
text += 'today ?';

alert(text);
```